# How can I interface a C++ class to Java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm currently working on integrating a C++ code with DLL dependencies to Java through JNI. I need to retain the object instance of the C++ for the subsequent call through Java.

Could anyone help me to understand how to pass the class instance to Java. Appreciate the help here.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <UIL.hpp>
#include <DeviceInfo.hpp>

typedef HINSTANCE LibraryHandle;
// pre-define UIL library entry points
typedef UIL* create_uil(const char*, bool, int, const char**);
typedef void delete_uil(UIL*);

const char* uilDriver;
bool uilAbsolute;
int uilParmCount;
static LibraryHandle uilHandle;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   uilHandle = LoadLibrary(TEXT("UIL.dll"));    
   if (uilHandle != NULL)
   {
      create_uil* createUIL = (create_uil*)GetProcAddress(uilHandle, "createUIL");
      uil = createUIL(uilDriver, uilAbsolute, uilParmCount, uilParms);  
      **//I need to return the instance UIL to JAVA**
   }
}
```

UIL.hpp

```
class UIL {
public:

  //! constructor for the UIL
    UIL(const char * driver_name, bool absolute, int parm_count, const char* parms[]);
  ~UIL();
  CPPEXTERN void infoString(char* str, int size);
  CPPEXTERN int deviceCount();
  CPPEXTERN int getDeviceKey(int index);
  int getCurrentDevice();
  CPPEXTERN int getCurrentDeviceIndex();
  int setDevice(int key);
  CPPEXTERN int setDeviceIndex(int index);
  CPPEXTERN int getDeviceInfo(DeviceInfo* di);
  CPPEXTERN int getAllDevices(DeviceInfo* di, int array_size);
  CPPEXTERN int send(unsigned char* buffer);
  CPPEXTERN int getNumWaiting(int &waiting);
  CPPEXTERN int receive();
  CPPEXTERN int lockDevice(int index, bool lock);
  CPPEXTERN bool isLocked(int index);
  CPPEXTERN int receiveInfo(int command_code, int argc, ...);
  CPPEXTERN int ioctl(int command_code, int argc, ...);
  CPPEXTERN int errInfo(int command_code, int argc, ...);
  int deviceListChangeCallback();
  CPPEXTERN void setLoggingLevel(int level);
  void getVersion(int& major, int& minor, int& revision);
  void getDriverVersion(int& major, int& minor, int& revision);
  const char* errStr(int err_code);
  UILAbstractDriver * getDriver() { return driver; }

private:
  UILAbstractDriver* driver;
  int last_key;
  int key_map[MAX_DEVICE_COUNT];
  int logging_level;
  char driver_name[81];
  void* io_argv[50];
  int device_index;
};
```

Comment: You can pass memory addresses as a `jlong` which turns into a `long` in Java.  You can use this address from Java.

Comment: I try to do that earlier. However, I'm not sure how to do it correctly. long valueToReturn = (long) &UIL; however I cannot recast it back to uil = (*UIL) valueToReturn; It post an error

Comment: Have you tried JNA? Makes your life so much easier. For this question, it provides a `Pointer` class on the Java side to represent `void*`.

Comment: `uil = (*UIL) valueToReturn` *is* an error. It should be `uil = (UIL*) valueToReturn`. Rather trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the answer using JNA:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <UIL.hpp>
#include <DeviceInfo.hpp>

typedef HINSTANCE LibraryHandle;
// pre-define UIL library entry points
typedef UIL* create_uil(const char*, bool, int, const char**);
typedef void delete_uil(UIL*);

const char* uilDriver;
bool uilAbsolute;
int uilParmCount;
static LibraryHandle uilHandle;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UIL* Initialize(int hba, int port)  
{
   uilHandle = LoadLibrary(TEXT("UIL.dll"));    
   if (uilHandle != NULL)
   {
      create_uil* createUIL = (create_uil*)GetProcAddress(uilHandle, "createUIL");
      uil = createUIL(uilDriver, uilAbsolute, uilParmCount, uilParms);  
      return uil;              }
}
```

JAVA

```
public interface UILInterfaceNative extends Library{
    public PointerByReference Initialize(int hba, int port);
    public int Scan(PointerByReference uil);
}

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        UILInterfaceNative uil = (UILInterfaceNative)Native.loadLibrary("UILInterfaceNative", UILInterfaceNative.class);
        PointerByReference uilPointer = new PointerByReference();
        uilPointer = uil.Initialize(0, 2);
        int device = uil.Scan(uilPointer);
        System.out.println("Device found: " + device);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Android.html) to auto generate the java native methods and corresponding methods in jni, it saves time all you need is to define a configuration file that will include the methods defined in the specified header files. Here is an example

**jni_interface.i**

```
%module MyNativeModule

%{
#include "native_header_file.h"
#include "native_header_file2.h"
%}

%include "arrays_java.i";
%include "enumtypeunsafe.swg"
%javaconst(1);

%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
    static {
        try {
            java.lang.System.loadLibrary("my-native-lib");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            java.lang.System.err.println("my-native-lib native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
            java.lang.System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            java.lang.System.loadLibrary("my-native-lib2");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            java.lang.System.err.println("my-native-lib2 native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
            java.lang.System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            java.lang.System.loadLibrary("my-native-lib3");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            java.lang.System.err.println("my-native-lib3 native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
            java.lang.System.exit(1);
        }        
    }
%}

%include "native_header_file.h"
%include "native_header_file2.h" of a config file:
```

So basically you can specify header files which contains the methods you want to use in Java and the native libraries you would like to load.

here is a .bat you may run every time you change native methods to run swig automatically and re-generate the methods.

**swig.bat**

```
rd java\com\demo\my_project_name\my-native-core\headers /Q /S
md java\com\demo\my_project_name\my-native-core\headers
swig.exe -java -package com.demo.my_project_name.my-native-core.headers -includeall -verbose -outdir java\com\demo\my_project_name\my-native-core\headers -c++ -I\usr\local\include -I\System\Frameworks\JavaVM.frameworks\Headers -I.\jni -o jni\jiw.cpp jni_interface.i
```